# How to abstract multiple similar function components (providers) in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have several `providers / contexts` in a React app that do the same, that is, CRUD operations calling a Nestjs app:

```
export const CompaniesProvider = ({children}: {children: any}) => {
  const [companies, setCompanies] = useState([])

  const fetchCompany = async () => {
    // etc.
    try {
      // etc.
      setCompanies(responseData)
    } catch (error) {}
  }

  const updateCompany = async () => {
    // etc.
    try {
      // etc.
    } catch (error) {}
  }

  // same for delete, findOne etc..

  return (
    <CompaniesContext.Provider value={{ 
      companies, 
      saveSCompany, 
    }}>
      {children}
    </CompaniesContext.Provider>
  )
}

export const useCompanies = () => useContext(CompaniesContext)
```

Another provider, for instance, the Technology model would look exactly the same, it just changes the api url:

```
export const TechnologiesProvider = ({children}: {children: any}) => {
  const [technologies, setTechnologies] = useState([])

  const fetchTechnology = async () => {
    // etc.
    try {
      // etc.
      setTechnologies(responseData)
    } catch (error) {}
  }

  const updateTechnology = async () => {
    // etc.
    try {
      // etc.
    } catch (error) {}
  }

  // same for delete, findOne etc..

  return (
     <TechnologiesContext.Provider value={{ 
       technologies, 
       savesTechnology, 
     }}>
        {children}
     </TechnologiesContext.Provider>
  )
}

export const useTechnologies = () => useContext(TechnologiesContext)
```

What is the best way to refactor? I would like to have an abstract class that implements all the methods and the different model providers inherit the methods, and the abstract class just needs the api url in the constructor..

But React prefers function components so that we can use hooks like useState.

Should I change function components to class components to be able to refactor? But then I lose the hooks capabilities and it's not the react way nowadays.

Another idea would be to inject the abstract class into the function components, and the providers only call for the methods.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to achieve it is to create a factory function that gets a `url` (and other parameters if needed) and returns a `provider` & `consumer`

This is an example for such function:

```
export const contextFactory = (url: string) => {
  const Context = React.createContext([]); // you can also get the default value from the fn parameters

  const Provider = ({ children }: { children: any }) => {
    const [data, setData] = useState([]);

    const fetch = async () => {
      // here you can use the url to fetch the data
      try {
        // etc.
        setData(responseData);
      } catch (error) {}
    };

    const update = async () => {
      // etc.
      try {
        // etc.
      } catch (error) {}
    };

    // same for delete, findOne etc..

    return (
      <Context.Provider
        value={{
          data,
          save
        }}
      >
        {children}
      </Context.Provider>
    );
  };

  const hook = () => useContext(Context)

  return [Provider, hook]
};
```

And this is how you can create new providers & consumers

```
const [CompaniesProvider, useCompanies] = contextFactory('http://...')
const [TechnologiesProvider, useTechnologies] = contextFactory('http://...')
```

Comment: very nice solution. The issue that I see is with the types. Having one factory complicates a lot working with types. I think I prefer to create a class with the methods logic, and have a file per model

Comment: can you elaborate on how to use it? I am using your solution, data fetching is properly done, setData too, but component where I used the component sticks to the initial state of the context, it's not updated with new values. Any idea why?

Comment: Please create a sandbox and I will take a look

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating a class representing the CRUD operations:

```
export class CrudModel {
  private api = externalUrls.api;
  constructor(private modelUrl: string) {}

  async fetchRecords() {
    const url = `${this.api}/${this.modelUrl}`

    try {
      const response = await fetch(url, {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
          'Content-type': 'application/json'
        },
      })
      return await response.json()
    } catch (error) {}
  }

  // removeRecord
  // updateRecord
  // saveRecord
}
```

Then for every provider I reduced the code, since I just call an instance of the `CrudModel`, which has the method implementations.

```
type Technology = {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}

type Context = {
  technologies: Technology[];
  saveTechnology: any;
  removeTechnology: any;
  updateTechnology: any;
}

const TechnologiesContext = createContext<Context>({
  technologies: [],
  saveTechnology: null,
  removeTechnology: null,
  updateTechnology: null,
})

export const TechnologiesProvider = ({children}: {children: any}) => {
  const [technologies, setTechnologies] = useState([])
  const router = useRouter()

  const crudModel = useMemo(() => {
    return new CrudModel('technologies')
  }, [])

  const saveTechnology = async (createForm: any): Promise<void> => {
    await crudModel.saveRecord(createForm)
    router.reload()
  }

  // fetchTechnologies
  // removeTechnology
  // updateTechnology

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
      const fetchedTechnologies = await crudModel.fetchRecords()
      setTechnologies(fetchedTechnologies)
    }

    fetchData()
  }, [crudModel])

return (
    <TechnologiesContext.Provider value={{ 
      technologies, 
      saveTechnology, 
      removeTechnology ,
      updateTechnology,
    }}>
      {children}
    </TechnologiesContext.Provider>
  )
}
```

This way I can have types for every file, and it's easy to debug / maintain. Having just one factory function like previous answer it feels cumbersome to follow data flow. The downside is that there is some repetition of code among the provider files. Not sure if I can refactor further my answer